# Residues of complex circular functions

Tags: definite-integrals, residue-calculus, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to evaluate an integral of a circular function:

$I=\int \frac{1}{\alpha\cos\theta+\beta\sin\theta+\gamma} d\theta$ over the interval $[0, 2\pi]$, where $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ are parameters.

I have specified constraints such that the integral will always converge, i.e. $|\alpha|+|\beta|\leq|\gamma|$, and want to compute this integral in terms of its parameters.

By changing the variables to complex ones, we are left with a quadratic on the denominator, which can be solved to reveal the two simple poles.

The integral is now 2 $\oint \frac{1}{(ai+b)z^2+(2ic)z+(ai-b)} dz$, the poles occurring at $\frac{-\gamma c+/-i\sqrt{\gamma^2-\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{\alpha i+\beta}$.

I want to use $\oint f(z)= 2\pi i \Sigma Res(f,c)$, but when evaluating the residue at each singularity the integral ends up being 0, which I think is wrong somewhere.

Please give me a hand.

Comment: If you did the usual change: $\;z=e^{i\theta}\;$ and etc., then you'll get a complex integral around $\;|z|=1\;$ ....are the poles of the resulting function in $\;z\;$ **inside** this circle? Otherwise you'd have to take $\;z=re^{i\theta\;$ according to the values of the parameters $\;\alpha,\beta,\gamma\;$ ...and that looks pretty messy and ugly.

Comment: Yes that was the change used and its now a contour integral on the unit circle. What is confusing me is that the roots are currently given in terms of the parameters $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. In similar questions it is possible to determine whether or not a root/singularity lies in the circle but I don't see how to infer this with these specific singularities?

Comment: @DonAntonio ^^^

Comment: Well, the question remains: are the roots of that quadratic within the unit circle or not? If they aren't then no wonder the integral is zero, and it wouldn't surprise me also if they both were...but what about the possibility that only one root is inside? We must also rule out the possibility that one of the roots is **on** the circle...

Comment: I've been assuming at least one of the roots lies inside the circle because the answer is expected to be in terms of the parameters, not just 0 kind of thing. Should we just trial/ impose restrictions on the parameters to explore what happens in each circumstance? I am struggling to see which of the roots would lie inside as different values of the parameters would change the situation immensely. Thank you for your replies thus far.